Powerbi dataset, After update to new datasource using rest api got error
I have a dataset with exisiting datasource and generated report. we planned to migrate to new gateway. And we created a new gateway and then created the new datasource and updated to new datasource using this api https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/Default.UpdateDatasources
After updating the new datasource. In power bi web app, lineage view datasource information are not showing. while clicking on settings it show below error.
one or more cloud datasource for the semantic model has been deleted. Recreate cloud datasource
please help me to resolve this issue
Thanks in Advance
